# Problem including PDF 1.6 files in XeTeX with MikTeX

Tags: graphics, xetex, pdf, miktex

Here's the MWE for my problem:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Adobe Garamond}

\begin{document}
text
\begin{figure}
  \centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5in]{file.pdf}  
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I'm trying to compile this using xelatex, and am including file.pdf which is PDF 1.6.

When I compile on Ubuntu using TeXLive 2009, I get a warning about the version of the PDF file:

```
** WARNING ** Version of PDF file (1.6) is newer than version limit specification.
```

but the file compiles fine otherwise.

However, on MikTeX (v 2.9 64 bit) on cygwin, I get the following message:

```
** WARNING ** Version of PDF file (1.6) is newer than version limit specification.
** WARNING ** No image converter available for converting file "file.pdf" to PDF format.
** WARNING ** >> Please check if you have 'D' option in config file.
** WARNING ** pdf: image inclusion failed for "file.pdf".
```

The versions of xelatex are essentially the same. Some googling indicated a problem with dvipdfmx, but I'm confused as to what this has to do with xelatex. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to raise the PDF version of the document itself. Locate the file `dvipdfmx.cfg`, the configuration file of the driver program XeTeX uses, and edit the `V` line to be

```
V  6
```

Don't forget to put the default settings back afterwards — they are there for a reason! Instead of modifying the original file you can also make a copy in your local TEXMF tree.

Comment: Hmm. I found the global file and changed it. I also made a local copy. to no avail. Is there some tex config that I also need to run after making the change ?

Comment: @Suresh: No, it should work right away. Perhaps a MikTeX user can tell more.

Comment: The file contains:

    %% dvipdfmx.cfg: Dvipdfmx configuration file
    %%
    %% DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE DIRECTLY! It will be overwritten.
    %%
    %% Run
    %%
    %%   initexmf --edit-config-file dvipdfmx
    %%
    %% to edit Dvipdfmx configuration parameters.