# \includegraphics{<pdf image>} is dropping items (comments) from the <pdf image> file. Can pdfTeX support inclusion of PDF 1.6?

Tags: graphics, pdftex, pdf

I have a pdf file, one page. When included in Latex using `\includegraphics`, the resulting image (in the compiled pdf) is not the same as what in the image pdf file that was included.

It dropped a letter in the formula. This might be due to the version number warning Tex Live is giving below or the warning about `Subtype in Resources` which I do not understand.

Here is a MWE, and link to download the pdf file in question:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}%
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[]{p}
\end{document}
```

The warning I get is

```
pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file ./p.pdf): PDF inclusion: found PDF 
version <1.6>, but at most version <1.5> allowed
```

Also

```
pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file ./p.pdf): PDF inclusion: 
Subtype in Resources dict is not a name (key 'Subtype', type <stream>); 
ignored.>] (./foo.aux)
```

Here is pdfinfo about the image file p.pdf

```
pdfinfo p.pdf
Creator:        Canon 
Producer:        
CreationDate:   Fri Oct  7 10:25:56 2011
ModDate:        Tue Sep 29 13:04:09 2015
Tagged:         no
Form:           AcroForm
Pages:          1
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      455.352 x 177.466 pts
Page rot:       0
File size:      38071 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.6
```

Here is side-by-side showing the difference

[image]

I am using Tl 2015 on Linux. Here is a [link](http://12000.org/tmp/092915/) to the folder with the pdf file p.pdf used in the above Latex MWE.

Here is the file list (I just did a `tlmgr update --all` again just in case) This is the current file list after the update

```
*File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size11.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0p Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
supp-pdf.mkii
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
       p.pdf    Graphic file (type pdf)
 ***********
```

The question is: How to handle this problem? does one need to change the version of the pdf file itself, or change some configuration settings in TL itself?

Related question [Problem including PDF 1.6 files in XeTeX with MikTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29742/problem-including-pdf-1-6-files-in-xetex-with-miktex)

Comment: @JohnKormylo I just run `tlmgr update --all` again, and the pdftex did not change versions, I saw it updating few other packages.  pdftex remained at v0.06d as giving in the above list. I still get same warnings, and the problem remains.  Running on Linux, TL 2015. Will update my question with the current filelist just in case.

Comment: Does [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50834/2417) help?

Comment: @IanThompson thanks, but it did _not_ fix the problem. This is what I did `\documentclass[11pt]{article}%
\pdfinclusioncopyfonts=1
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\listfiles
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[]{p}
\end{document}`  compiled with pdflatex, looked at the pdf file, and it is still missing the `s` there.

Comment: @cfr I tried. but it is still missing. Here is example: `\pdfminorversion=7
\pdfinclusioncopyfonts=1
\documentclass[11pt]{article}%
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\listfiles
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[]{p}
\end{document}`, I also tried just this `\pdfminorversion=7
\documentclass[11pt]{article}%
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\listfiles
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[]{p}
\end{document}` no change. Letter is missing.

Comment: The link to the related question in your post is broken and I don't know what it is supposed to point to. Can you fix it?

Comment: The problem seems to be related to the fact that the 's' is a pdf comment (annotation).

Comment: @cfr fixed link. It was question about using PDF image file version 1.6 in Miktex.

Comment: @IanThompson yes, the 's' was added by the instructor. But I need it to show up when I include the pdf. Can includegraphics include comments in pdf file also? I'll update the title to mention this. I was not sure what the problem is, and still not sure.

Comment: I see different things when opening the pdf with different viewers (Preview and Acrobat), none of which just show the added 's'. Since the pdf has been scanned and is not a vector file anyway, I suggest exporting what you want as a png image and including that file instead.

Comment: It would probably be easier to type in the equation.

Comment: @JohnKormylo  This is only part of the larger problem question. Yes, I can type the question by hand. But I have many pdf files with comments like this in them added to the pdf file, so if there is a way to include comments like these it will be better in the long term.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The two error messages concern two distinct problems. The first is easily solved. The second less so.

## First problem: PDF cannot include a PDF which uses a higher version format

This is the first error message you get:

```
pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file ./p.pdf): PDF inclusion: found PDF 
version <1.6>, but at most version <1.5> allowed
```

By default, current pdfTeX produces PDF version 1.5. However, it can produce other versions, up to 1.7. In order to include a PDF which uses format version 1.6, your PDF should be at least version 1.6.

Add either

```
\pdfminorversion=6
```

for version 1.6 or

```
\pdfminorversion=7
```

for version 1.7 as the first line in your `.tex` file.

Note that 'first line' means *first line* i.e. this is *not* part of your preamble - it comes *before* `\documentclass...` etc. as the option needs to be set very early in order to be effective.

## Second problem: malformed PDF

This is the second error message:

```
pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file ./p.pdf): PDF inclusion: 
Subtype in Resources dict is not a name (key 'Subtype', type <stream>); 
ignored.>] (./foo.aux)
```

Basically, the software which created the PDF appears to have produced a malformed PDF which pdfTeX cannot make sense of. The PDF viewer can make sense of it, apparently, although it certainly does not look right in mine. The font, spacing and alignment of the disappearing `s` looks wrong in your screen shot as well.

The real solution here is to persuade the creator software to produce a valid PDF. Apart from the malformation which renders the PDF invalid, no fonts are embedded which is also problematic (although this doesn't make the PDF invalid).

If that is not an option, I would first check what output *should* be displayed here and then either just typeset the required content normally or turn the PDF into a PNG and include that. The PNG option is not at all ideal, but if the other options aren't possible, it may be the best you can do.

Comment: thanks again for the hint. But for some reason, it is still missing that letter. Here is what I tried `\pdfminorversion=6
\documentclass[11pt]{article}%
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\listfiles
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[]{p}
\end{document}` and tried '7'. No change. I have the pdf image file in the link I posted if you like to try yourself. Also tried `\pdfminorversion=6
\pdfinclusioncopyfonts=1
\documentclass[11pt]{article}%
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\listfiles
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[]{p}
\end{document}` and no change. letter still missing.

Comment: @Nasser Please see my edit. The PDF is not valid. That's the basic problem. It is complaining that it doesn't match the specification which pdfTeX uses to make sense of the content. And I'm not clear whether the PDF viewer is doing much better - presumably, even if `s` is correct, it shouldn't look quite like *that*! ??

Comment: @cfr --- The 's' has been inserted as a pdf comment.

Comment: Converting to png worked for me (but not pdf).

Comment: @cfr I am sure the 's' was added by the instructor later on. I know it does not look the same as the other fonts. But since it is "inside" the pdf file, I assumed it will show up in Latex. I thought whatever shows up on the screen when looking at the pdf file, will also show up when including the pdf file in Latex as graphics. I'll just take screen shot for now and save to png and use png for this one problem. Screen shot always works ;)

Comment: Loading it into GIMP and saving back to PDF worked as well.

Comment: @JohnKormylo thanks. I ended up doing screen shot of the problem, saving to png using paint.exe on windows, then used PDF pro to convert the png to pdf file. Now the 's' shows in there in the pdf saved since it was screen shot.

Comment: @Nasser You're welcome. I'm not actually sure if this is because the kind of annotation is not really defined in PDF 1.6, whether it is corrupted somehow, or whether it is a limitation of pdfTeX. However, while a correct annotation wouldn't give a warning/error, it also wouldn't be included - the annotation I tried just got lost. And this is expected: see page 2 of the `pdfpages` documentation.

Comment: @Nasser You can extract and reinsert annotations using the `pax` package. However, the comment in this PDF cannot be extracted because you get just the same complaint about the PDF dictionary. Heiko Oberdiek's a PDF expert and would know exactly what is going on. I, sadly, am not and, therefore, do not :(.

Answer (score 3):

The disappearing 's' is a pdf comment (annotation). The problem will go away if you 'flatten' the pdf so that this is no longer the case. One way to do this is to print the pdf into another pdf. On a Mac I open the file in Preview or Skim (not an Adobe product since these block the procedure) and go to File -> Print, then click PDF -> Save as PDF and enter a new filename. You will probably need to crop the new image.

Comment: If I open the pdf in Preview I don't see the letter 's', but the letter 'e' appears in several places. There is also some text at the top about Homework Set #3. The file seems to have some problems.

Comment: @erik --- The text at the top is partially cropped. I don't see the extraneous instances of 'e' though.

Comment: I see them with Preview, but not with Acrobat. The text about a homework set appears in both viewers, but in slightly different positions.

Comment: I used `pdftk` to flatten the PDF and still got the same problem. It is part of an annotation, but the structure of the annotation doesn't seem to be correct.

Comment: @cfr --- I tried `pdftk` as well; it didn't work for me either. Printing to a new pdf seems to fix the problem (at least on my machine).

Comment: The image file is a cropped problem from the original file the teacher emailed us. But the same problem shows up in the original file as well. So me cropping the problem out is not related. Please see the original file here I just uploaded. [link](http://12000.org/tmp/092915/). I normally take out each problem from the pdf file (using the PDF pro program I have on windows that can crop regions of pdf pages) and put it on its own file so I can include it in the right location in my latex. I do not think the problem is due to cropping.

Comment: @IanThompson But that is not the same as flattening and doesn't say anything about the correctness of the original file. At least, not as far as I know.

Comment: @cfr --- OK, my terminology may be inaccurate there. Nevertheless, printing to a new pdf did fix the problem on my machine.

Comment: @IanThompson Oh, yes. That may be right. I didn't mean to deny your testimony ;). When annotations are well-formed, pdfTeX seems to just ignore them. At least, so my minimal testing suggests....

Comment: @Nasser I agree: the problem is in the original PDF.